# What is the correct syntax for this operation?

Tags: python

Writing a game and no matter what I try it keeps giving me a syntax error for the 'as'.

I have tried looking through StackOverflow / changing my code to find a workaround but I have been unable to fix it so far

```py
winner = input("Winner test username")
winnerscore = input("Test score")
open("leaderboardtest.txt","a") as leaderboard
leaderboard.write = "/n" , winner , " : " , winnerscore
```

(winner and winnerscore variables would have been made earlier just wrote it here during testing)

Invalid syntax highlight on the 'as'.

(I know this is a comparatively simple problem to other things on StackOverflow but I would appreciate any support.)

Comment: `with open("leaderboardtest.txt","a") as leaderboard:`

Comment: And `leaderboard.write = "/n" , winner , " : " , winnerscore` should probably be `leaderboard.write("{}: {}". format(winner, winnerscore))`. Your `/n` is likely meant as a line break (which would be `\n`), but that's included in the `write()` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There you go.

```
winner = input("Winner test username")
winnerscore = input("Test score")
with open("leaderboardtest.txt","a") as leaderboard:
    string_to_write = "\n" + winner + " : " + winnerscore
    leaderboard.write(string_to_write)
```

Comment: I use string_to_write as the format for the result right?

Comment: Correct. You could directly use `leaderboard.write("\n" + winner + " : " + winnerscore)` as well.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you have used incorrect syntax for writing text into file.

```py
f = open("leaderboardtest.txt","a") # open file for append operation
f.write('\n' + winner + ' : ' + winnerscore) # write data whatever you want
f.close() # close file
```